# Write in Heroku Postsqrl database from rails development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

Is there any way in which I can access my production heroku postsqrl database from the development environment? I want to run a function on my development environment and then depending on the outcome create new records on my production database.

Currently I can only access the production database by using `heroku run rails c` in the console, and create new objects with `Post.new()` etc...

Is there also a way that I can code this so that it does this automatically?

Btw I run the function on my development variable because I am scraping a bunch of data with kimurai and doing that via heroku on my production environment takes a bunch of RAM is a pain in the a**.

Thanks!

Comment: Just copy the database URL from the Heroku config into your local database.yml

Comment: @spickermann is right. You can get the connection settings via `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`. And you can then connect to that database either by it as an environmental variable for the process with for example `DATABASE_URL =  $(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL) rake my_task` or you can use [`connected_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-connected_to) if your Rails version supports it.

Comment: You can also just write the DATABASE_URL into your encrypted secrets if you want easier access.